# How can I use properties as fields with MongoEngine?

Tags: mongodb, dynamic, field, pymongo, mongoengine

Essentially I'd like to be able to defined dynamic fields by using a property decorator on my MongoEngine models. Something like this:

```
class Model(Document):
    foo = StringField()

    @property
    def bar(self):
        return 'baz'

m = Model(foo='abc'); m.save()
```

Then I'd like to be able to query by the property. Something like this:

```
Model.objects(bar='baz')
```

I thought maybe DynamicDocument might provide this facility. But that doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions? Could a custom property decorator handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties don't act like fields no data is stored in the database, so you cant query the database for a match.

Comment: Right, not sure what I was thinking. Apologies for not accepting this sooner. Thanks!